# javascript oop assistance

Tags: javascript, client-side

I'm having trouble with javascript's oop.  I have a small code snippet which is similar to the code I'm using in my project.  I wrote a small code example, I'm having trouble with this too.  I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong with my Javascript, so my code will work.

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.Display = {};

Display.prototype.text = function(str) {
  document.write(str + '<br />');
  window.alert(str);
};

var Jacob = new Person('Jacob');

Jacob.Display.text('Hello World!');
```

This small code example is supposed to display the text hello world.  The trouble I'm having is that the line `"Jacob.Display.Text('Hello World!');"` is not working.

Comment: I would have guessed that `Display.prototype.text` would have given some kind of "is undefined" or "is not a function" exception.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen is correct. Your browser has a JavaScript console; I suggest looking at the error that shows up there.

Comment: Also, you should not use document.write after the page load!

Comment: I used JS console and got a ReferenceError:  Display is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.display = {
    text : function(str) {
        document.write(str + '<br />');
        window.alert(str);
    }
};

var Jacob = new Person('Jacob');
Jacob.display.text('Hello World!');
```

(Also note the lowercase 'd' in 'display'; leave uppercase initials for constructors)

Comment: What if I wanted to add properties and methods to the display object from the outside, would the code be Display.prototype.*?

Comment: There's no `Display.prototype`, just `Person.prototype.display`. So `Person.prototype.display.foo = function() {return 'bar';}`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're attempting to do, but this is probably closer to what you want.

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.element = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(this.element);
}

Person.prototype.display = function(str) {
  this.element.textContent = str;
  console.log(this.name + ' set to ' + str);
};

var jacob = new Person('Jacob');

jacob.display('Hello World!');
```